# Does Small World's Dragon Master allow conquering non-adjacent regions?

Tags: small-world

Dragon Master:

> Once per turn, you may conquer a Region
>   using a single Race token, regardless of the
>   number of enemy tokens defending it. Once
>   conquered, place your Dragon there...

Does this allow you to conquer any region on the map, even if it's not adjacent to a region you already control? In a game I played last night, it was ruled that it could do this. However I don't agree with that ruling since it doesn't explicitly grant that exception.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The Dragon does not fly or give the race flying.  (Therefore you can normally<sup>*</sup> only conquer adjacent areas).

The Dragon does not do the conquering, only allow you to conquer an area with a single race token.  You place the Dragon after you conquer the area.

<sup>*</sup>*normally used as I don't have all the expansions and for all I know there is an edge case out there!*

Comment: One edge case would be the Dragon Master Spiderines:

For conquest purposes, your Spiderines consider all Regions  bordering a Chasm as adjacent to the Regions they already occupy. For your first conquest, you may enter the board through any Region bordering a Chasm.

Comment: A humorous reminder of this rule is actually the artwork on the dragon token itself. If you look closely, you'll see that it is a walking dragon, not a flying one, and that it is being coaxed forward with human bait dangling from a long stick.